# How to return Boolean value in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

In the following code, I'm trying to get a Boolean value from my method `IsWinning`, and then I want to create while it's false, keep playing lottery thing. If we win and the result is true, the program exits. The other methods I wrote are irrelevant so I didn't add them to code here.

How can I create a while loop here, with this perspective of mine or any other perspective?

```
    int machine [] = machineGenerator();
    int user [] = userGenerating();
    boolean result= false;
    do {
        printUserTicket(user);
        printMachineTicket(machine);
        isWinnerTicket(user, machine);
    } while (result=!true);
        //how can i assign booelan value here from my IsWinningMethod

}

public static void isWinnerTicket(int[] a , int [] b) {
    int hits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]){
                    hits++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(hits == 6){
        System.out.println("You Win");
        
    }else {
        System.out.println("You Lose");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: the conditions guarding `if`-statements are of type `boolean`.

Comment: What prevents you from creating a loop or from returning a `Boolean` (or, probably better here, a `boolean`)?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with both of you here. Since the word *Boolean* is derived from a name, *Boole*, it is spelled with capital *B* in English. And in Java a primitive `boolean` is better than a `Boolean` object for our purpose. This was probably also what the OP meant by *Boolean value*.

Comment: Thank you all of you. I was thinking completely wrong about method types and their working styles (boolean, int, double etc.). Now i figured out with the following answer of @OleV.V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare your `isWinnerTicket` method `boolean` instead of `void`. Just substitute the word.
2. In your method, to return either true or false use

   ```
   return hits == 6;
   ```

   Since `hits == 6` will evaluate to either true or false, this is what you need.
3. In your main program you want to pick up the Boolean value that was returned. I see two good ways:

   1. Assign to the variable you already have:

      ```
          result = isWinnerTicket(user, machine);
      ```
   2. Put your method call directly into your loop condition:

      ```
      } while (! isWinnerTicket(user, machine));
      ```

      The exclamation mark here, `!`, means *not*.

   Make your pick.